# Loading properties file in storm cluster mode

Tags: apache-storm

In my topology there is a small piece of code loading configurations from properties in classpath

```
InputStream is=getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dev.properties");
p.load(is);
```

It works great when I run jar in local mode storm, but when I try it in cluster mode, it fails with NullPointerException.
The properties file is in src/main/resources(Maven structure) and properly included in jar file.

Is there any possible reason?

Besides, I face a lot of trouble when I run some topology with outbound interaction for example ElasticSearch in cluster mode storm. Even though it works perfect in local mode storm.

What should I think before using cluster mode storm?

Comment: did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your properties object while building topology and then pass it to your bolts/spouts via constructor where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure a Network file system in your storm cluster and then place that property file in NFS location, read property file from this location.